# Document Set Setting causes error

Tags: sharepoint-server

Help with Document Set Content type

I had modified or updated parent Document Set. and changed it back.
Now When I create a new Document Set. and goto Document Set setting I am getting error.

attached is the screen shots.[image]

ULS Logs does not say much except. 
User Agent not available, file operations may not be optimized

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to create a new site collection and import , export all sub sites into the new site collection and it worked.